# After running bundle install I get a rails_factor12 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running `bundle install` and i get this error:

```
Could not find gem 'rails_factor12 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

My ruby -v is 2.0.0
My rails -v is 4.2.0

I am using rbenv

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'

    gem 'unicorn'

    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
    gem 'sqlite3'

    # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
    gem 'byebug'

    # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

    # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
    gem 'spring'
end

group :production do 
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_factor12'
end
```

I already added tried to updating Rails, and bundler. I also tried removing my Gemlock file, none of that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the name of the gem.

```
gem 'rails_12factor'
```